# IBM Mobilefirst Platform Studio 7.0 (Worklight) Failed to copying nativeResources for Blackberry 10 environment

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

I am receiving this error when trying to build app for Blackberry 10 environment on OS X using Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2):

```
[2015-03-26 13:46:46]             Starting build process: application 'FirstMobileFirst', all environments 
[2015-03-26 13:46:46] FWLST1123I: Using BlackBerry WEBWORKS_HOME path: /Applications/BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.2.0.15 
[2015-03-26 13:46:56] FWLST1040E: blackberry10 build failed: Failed copying nativeResources to native project (blackberry10)
[2015-03-26 13:46:57]             Application 'FirstMobileFirst' with all environments build finished with errors.
```

The Blackberry WebWorks app is installed and the WEBWORKS_HOME variable exported before starting Eclipse/Worklight.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this myself and my files from the nativeResources folder were copied to the native folder.

Suggestion:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Delete workspace
3. In terminal "open $TMPDIR"
4. Delete the wlBuildResources folder
5. Open Eclipse
6. Try again with a new project